# Merging header content of all pages to the body in a word file

Tags: microsoft-word

I have generated some reports in pdf format using a sweave code in R. Those reports require slight editing. For that purpose, I converted those reports into Word files using Adobe Acrobat Reader. But after conversion, some portion of the text on the top gets included in header section. That poses some problems. So my question is, is there some way in Word through which I can remove headers from all the pages while merging the content in the header with the body or to not create headers while conversion of pdf to Word file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Some pdf readers give option to suppress repeated headers on each page while converting to doc. PDF nitro reader had such option in earlier versions but that feature has now been made paid in latest version. or check whether some online pdf to word convertor site is providing that option.
2. You can use ocr also, some ocr-s also give option to repeated headers,like Tessaract which is free. or find if any online ocr site is giving that option.

These will not merge headers to body text, these will rather put the header/ footer only once. If you want to merge header/ footer to text, it is as good as select text extraction tool, copy entire text from pdf and put that to a word document.